# MockObject property gets cleared after constructor

Tags: php, phpunit

Hi guys i'm currently writing a test for a function inside a class in my project.

```
function theTestFunction()
{
  $companyMock = $this->createMock(Company::class);
  $companyMock->method('getUser')->willReturn(new User());
  $companyMock->method('isActive')->willReturn(false);
  $companyMock->expects($this->once())->method('setActive')->with(true)->willReturn($companyMock);

  $manager = $this->getMockBuilder(CompanyManager::class)
    ->setMethods(['updateNewsletter'])
    ->setConstructorArgs([$companyMock])
    ->getMock();
  $manager->expects($this->once())->method('updateNewsletter');
  $manager->switchActivation();
}
```

But i don't understand why my stubbed method `getUser()` (called in the `updateNewsletter()`) returns null when i trigger the original function `switchActivation()` which is something like this

```
function switchActivation() : Company
{
    $this->company = $this->company->setActive(!$this->company->isActive());
    $this->company->save();
    $this->updateNewsletter();

    return $this->company;
}
```

This is the function failing the test

```
function updateNewsletter()
{
  $user = $this->company->getUser();
  // Do some other stuff...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of

```
->willReturn($companyMock)
```

use

```
->will($this->returnSelf())
```

Cf. https://phpunit.readthedocs.io/en/7.4/test-doubles.html#test-doubles-stubs-examples-stubtest4-php

Comment: Same results: getUser() gives NULL instead of a User instance... i really don't get it.